# groovy openni 1.5.4 upgrade error

Tags: openni, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
after reading Tullys post on ros-users, I just upgraded to openni 1.5.4 on my Ubuntu 12.10 machine via upgrade manager.
I got the following errors during the upgrade process:

```
"The upgrade will continue but the 'ps-engine' package may not be in a working state.Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

Could not install 'nite-dev' Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

Could not install the upgrades. The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a)."
```

So ps-engine is now a broken package, but I think that it is safe to remove it because now it is obsolete/deprecated, right? Besides, I runned openni_launch and image_view and the Kinect seems to be working.
Regarding nite-dev, I don't know if it is necessary but the problem seems that there is no quantal version of the package available.

Cheers,
Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51147/groovy-openni-1.5.4-upgrade-error/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is safe to remove ps-engine.

Sorry I forgot to mention the 3rd package changed package in my email.  The three packages changed are as follows:

- openni-dev -> libopenni-dev
- ps-engine -> libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev
- nite-dev -> libopenni-nite-dev

And there are a few dependencies that should be automatically installed:

- libopenni0
- libopennni-sensor-primesense0
- openni-utils

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-29**:
I tried doing the dist-upgrade. Now apt-get complains of "unmet dependencies". It is unable to remove the old packages or install the new ones. The broken dependencies are: `ros-fuerte-openni-{camera,kinect,tracker}` and `ros-groovy-openni-camera`.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-29**:
I finally got it unstuck by removing all those dependencies and all *their* dependencies.